# How to retrieve generated fields such as generated id or updated_at field by a trigger during insert/update in springboot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

In postgres it's possible to retrieve computed values using returning. I have a generated id field and a field called `updated_at` that is updated by a trigger whenever a row is modified.
I'd like to achieve something like this but looks like it's not working. Not sure it's the right syntax for bulk insert.

```java
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO entities VALUES :values RETURNING *",nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity> insertAndReturn(@Param("values") List<Entity> entities);
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

I have also looked into jdbctemplate but it seems we are losing the benefit of entity mapping and we need to write own customized mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work. Native SQL doesn't support multi-valued parameters. You have to list all parameters individually. You can try something like this

```java
default List<Entity> insertAndReturn(@Param("values") List<Entity> entities) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++ ) {
        entities.set(i, insertAndReturn(entities.get(i)));
    }
    return entities;
}
default Entity insertAndReturn(Entity entity) {
    return insertAndReturn(entity.getColumn1(), entity.getColumn2());
}
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO entities_table(column1, column2) VALUES (:column1, :column2) RETURNING *",nativeQuery = true)
Entity insertAndReturn(@Param("column1") String column1, @Param("column2") String column2);
```

Comment: so it's not possible to perform batch insert with list of params?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to encode the batch size in your SQL by listing out all parameters for every row you want to insert i.e. `... values (:col1_1, :col2_1), (:col1_2, :col2_2), (:col1_3, :col2_3), ...`